# Graphql java spring boot -- Scalar type error -- There is no scalar implementation for the named 'XXX' scalar type

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I want to make scalar type it will report an error
Even I use extended-scalars, It did not work at all.

- Version:

spring-boot: 2.7.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

- Code

```java
@Configuration
public class Conf {

    @Bean
    public GraphQLScalarType graphQLLong() {
        return ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong;
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: SchemaProblem{errors=[There is no scalar implementation for the named  'Long' scalar type]}
```

- Schema structure (a very simple one)

```
scalar Long

type Mutation {

}
```

- yml config

[image]
[image]
So what config was I lost?

Comment: how does your schema looks like?

Comment: I use a very simple schema to test

Comment: I add it in my issue

Answer (score 7):

Use this :

```
@Bean 
public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() { 
   return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder.scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong); 
}
```

Instead of :

```
@Bean
public GraphQLScalarType graphQLLong() {
   return ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this helped solving the problem here.

I was trying to add a custom type by >GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()...< but it it the same! thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much. My custom type bean definition didn't work but this solved my problem.

Comment: This helped me. I really need a custom type to convert timestamp to date, so I specified my custom class and its static method like this: `wiringBuilder.scalar(DealScalar.Date)`

Answer (score 4):

Include `graphql-java-extended-scalars` dependency:

https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars

And make sure in your `@Configuration` class you are using:

```java
@Bean
public graphql.schema.GraphQLScalarType extendedScalarLong() {
    return graphql.scalars.ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong;
}
```

Also, if you are defining your ExtendedScalar as a `@Bean`, then there's no need to specify it in `graphql.extended-scalars` property.

Comment: How about including multiple Scalar types? I want to add BigInt, UUID and other Scalars at once

Comment: @Mamurbek, then define a separate bean for each scalar type.